# getting the implementing object instance of an interface

Tags: java

How can I get the implementing object instance of an interface?

For example:

```
interface Animal{
   
    <T> T unwrap();
}
```

and its implementation:

```
class Cat implements Animal {
    
    public void jump(){..}

    public <T> T unwrap() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

Having this:

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
// did not work
cat.unwrap().jump();
```

Sure, I can do an explicit cast:

```
((Cat) cat).jump();
```

However, is there a way to get it automatically by using the unwrap-method?

Comment: How should `cat.unwrap().jump()` work when all you know is that `cat` references an `Animal`? What would you expect to happen if it happened to be a non-Cat animal? Also your `unwrap` method uses an unsafe cast so it will gladly try to return whatever but fail at runtime. Try `Integer foo = cat.unwrap()` and it will compile (but always fail at runtime).

Comment: So I need something like this:  `public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType){..}`

Comment: @nimo23 yes, if you want the cast to be checked (i.e. actually type-safe) then you need that. At which point you're just redirecting to `Class.cast` and the users of `unwrap` might as well just call that or cast manually, as there's extremely little difference at that point.

Comment: In your example you assume the animal is a cat. So what is the advantage over following code? `Cat cat = new Cat(); cat.jump();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common trick when using generics is to pass in the class as an argument. Since Class is generic, this allows you to define what type  is. This works for your example but I would argue that your explicit cast is cleaner. Sometimes frameworks use this trick so it is a useful one to know.

```
public class UnwrappingAnimals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        cat.unwrap(Cat.class).jump();   
    }
}

interface Animal{
    <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz);
}

class Cat implements Animal {
    
    public void jump(){
        System.out.println("I am jumping. Meow.");
    }

    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I only need a nasty `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on that unwrap()-method. However, I don't think we can get rid of them.

Comment: If you pass in `clazz` then you should really use `clazz.cast(this)` instead of `(T) this`. Otherwise you still have an unchecked cast and gained nothing of value.

Comment: @nimo23: `class.cast()` can help you get rid of that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Perfect solution! Thanks!

Comment: Great suggestions. I will refine the answer with clazz.cast. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of raw `<T>` you could use `<T extends Animal>` to make the usage clearer

Answer (score 1):

The visitor pattern fits your problem reasonably well. While it does not use generics, it does allow you to access the concrete class in a typesafe manner. Essentially, the visitor pattern is useful for adding functionality to a type hierarchy without adding methods to each class.

In the example below, it adds the ability to call the jump method, which only some of the classes in the hierarchy have. The implementation for the snail should probably do nothing but I have made it write a message to stderr for demo purposes.

The visitor pattern works by using Java's method overloading to end up at the correct method. First call cat.accept(jump). The cat object will then call jump.visit(this), which will end up at the correct method at runtime. I would say this is totally overkill for your example but it is useful for larger examples.

```
public class UnwrappingAnimals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        Animal snail = new Snail(); 
        
        AnimalVisitor jump = new JumpingVisitor();
        cat.accept(jump);
        snail.accept(jump);
    }
}

interface Animal{
    void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor);
}

class Cat implements Animal {
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
    
    public void jump(){
        System.out.println("I am jumping. Meow.");
    }
}

class Snail implements Animal {
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface AnimalVisitor {
    void visit(Cat cat);
    void visit(Snail snail);
}

class JumpingVisitor implements AnimalVisitor {

    public void visit(Cat cat) {
        cat.jump();
    }

    public void visit(Snail snail) {
        System.err.println("Snails don't jump!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't have to use the generics `<T>`, you can change the code, instead of using that, you can return a object of `Animal` inside the `unwrap` method (with return this).
And you can also add the `jump()` method in the `Animal` interface and in the Cat class overwrite both methods:

```
 interface Animal{

    Animal unwrap();
    void jump();
}

public class Cat implements Animal {

public void jump(){
    System.out.println("Jump");    
}

public Animal unwrap() {
    return this;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        cat.unwrap().jump();
    }
}
```

PD: Using that, I don't see necessary to use the `unwrap()` method.
But I guess this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

For your info, doing

```
cat.unwrap(Cat.class).jump()
```

as suggested by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110745/13510609), is almost the same as

```
((Cat) cat).jump()
```

just adding an additional call to `unwrap`.

The compiled code will include the cast and the call to the same `jump` method in both cases.
For example, the code

```
    Animal cat = new Cat();
    cat.unwrap(Cat.class).jump();   
    ((Cat) cat).jump();
```

is disassembled to

```
       0: new           #7                  // class Cat
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #9                  // Method Cat."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: ldc           #7                  // class Cat
      11: invokeinterface #10,  2           // InterfaceMethod Animal.unwrap:(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      16: checkcast     #7                  // class Cat
      19: invokevirtual #16                 // Method Cat.jump:()V
      22: aload_1
      23: checkcast     #7                  // class Cat
      26: invokevirtual #16                 // Method Cat.jump:()V
```

---

One advantage of using

```
interface Animal {
    <T> T unwrap();
}
```

is to avoid having to write the cast, like in:

```
Animal someAnimal;
...
Cat cat = someAnimal.unwrap();  // no cast needed, inferred by compiler
```

but again, the compiled code includes the *cast*, just not needed in the source code. Not sure if that is such a good practice...  will throw an `Exception` if the `Animal` is not an instance of `Cat`.

<sup>A good example is [emptyList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()) of `Collections`.</sup>